# Sending data wirelessly from one Android app to another phone

Tags: android, serversocket

I am creating an app that collects data in an app and it is stored in an array. I basically average the data in the array and I need to send it to another person's android phone (it would be like a notification that might appear once an hour at most).

I am relatively new to android app programming. So for my situation, I was thinking that I would have two separate apps. One collects data and transfers the information to the other app on a different phone. I probably would need to do some type of configuration to notify the other phone that it should be listening for info.

I was able to find an example which does something similar in the link https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

However, I was not sure if this is the best strategy because all I really need is a way to notify someone else's phone about the data being recorded on one app. Any recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: you can use firebase push notification for that.

Comment: Do you mean firebase cloud messaging?

Comment: yes, cloud messaging and firebase db, so one app will write and the other will syn the data on start. Firebase already provide that functionality.